# Can I access and pull out a nested array object and put this into root array object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have an array of items that I am pushing to an object using:

`items.map((item) => item )`

This pushes it to the object inside this `selectedItems` object like so:

[image]

The item above that called `selectedFolder` is how it should populate but for some reason it pushes it into its own nested array.

How can I pull them out so they populate the `selectedItems` like selectedFolder?

Thanks,
Mark

Comment: can you add you json ?

Comment: That is the json/array in the image above

Comment: From where do you get the data? Is there a reason that `selectedItems` is an array inside an array?

Comment: Sorry but it's not clear what you are asking. This would be easy to help if you could add expected output and orignal data

Comment: basically I have a function that selects all objects on a page and pushes them into selectedItems but instead of it being created inside its own object the `0: Array[3]` I need the items in the array to be pulled out so they sit in `selectedItems` exactly how the `selectedFolder` above is structured

Comment: Then I guess that is the code we should be looking at, not the one you have posted here...

Comment: Icepickle what do you mean? The code you are referring to just populates the array because its on a single button that just pushed one at a time not all three

Comment: What creates the `items` object? Items probably is something like [[object1, object2, object3]], so it is already "wrong" to begin with, the map  will just push the items in the first array into the object

Comment: `items.map((item) => item )` simply makes a shallow copy of `items`, like `items.slice()`.

Comment: I did a for loop instead here
`for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        this.$store.dispatch('SELECT_FOLDER',items[i].uuid)
      }`

This worked fine

Answer (score 0):

You are pushing an array into an array.

You could try writing a `for loop` to go over the items in your first array and push them into the other.